# Which Debuff Effects Stack/Interact?

Tags: team-fortress-2

There are five debuffs that exist in TF2 (that I can think of at the moment, that are player-caused and not Fear).  They are:

- On Fire: you take damage over time.
- Jarate: You take Mini-Crit damage.
- Bleeding: Damage over time but not Fire.
- Milked: Getting hit causes the person hitting you to be healed.
- Marked For Death: Mini-Crits that are not Jarate-inflicted

Now, say someone was unlucky enough to have all four of these effects on them at the same time.  Which of them would stack/interact with one another?

To be more specific:

- Would Fire or Bleeding do more damage to a Marked-For-Death or Jarate'd individual?
- Would a Milked individual provide constant health to the player who caused them to burn/bleed?
- Would the same Milked person provide more health while under the effects of Jarate or a Mark For death?
- Do these stacking effects change depending on the item that inflicted them? (Self-inflicted Marked-For-Death of Heavy/Soldier, vs. the Scout's Fan of War, or being hit by a Scout's Guillotine vs. a scout hitting himself with the Boston Basher).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the debuffs stack except for Marked for Death and Jarate (as they both provide mini-crits). Now for your bullet-point questions:

- Mini-crit fire (both Jarate and Marked for Death) deals one more point of fire damage (4 if you're not using the Degreaser, 3 if you are).
- Fire and bleed damage would indeed heal if their target is currently Milked.
- As recovery off of Milked is based off of damage dealt, the health recovered off mini-crit damage would increase (you would recover 2 health rather than 1 as your fire/bleed damage does 4 damage rather than 3).
- Debuffs do not differ in magnitude depending on the weapon that applied them, so these stacking effects would not change.

P.S. Credit to Powerlord for providing assistance and knowledge